# What type of applications Silverlight is designed for?

Tags: c#, silverlight, junior-programmer

I have 3 years experience in ASP.NET with C# and now I am learning Silverlight with [Beginning Silverlight 4 in C#](http://www.apress.com/9781430229889) book.

As I have completed my first 4 chapters, I am getting the feeling that Silverlight is just about creating RIA which can also be done with Flash.

What is a scope of Silverlight for a C# programmer?

Comment: Silverlight is also for windows phone 7.

Comment: Have you looked at [Is Silverlight only for eye-candy, or does it have a use in business?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/is-silverlight-only-for-eye-candy-or-does-it-have-a-use-in-business)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight is Microsoft's "replacement" for Flash.  It is meant to do what Flash does, although I would say that Microsoft's emphasis is different.  Silverlight is for making browser/device independent applications, especially RIA.  You could do a "dull" business app in Silverlight if you wanted to gain the browser/platform independence that Silverlight offers.  One area where Flash is often used but where Silverlight is (arguably) not intended to be strong is in keyframe-based animations (i.e. cartoons).